# simple array recursive instead of while

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

The code is in javascript. The goal of the highest function is to return the largest number in the array g. I want this to be recursive and no use of while loop or for loop. So the return value should be 732.
/// edit...i know that doing sort then pop the last item is the best approach but i was just practicing recursive function and too lazy to do sort. i understand quicksort and mergesort. at the time, it was 200am in the morning so i was tire.

```js
function highest(arr, index, largest)
{
    var largest =  largest || arr[0];

    if(index < arr.length)
    {
        if(arr[index] > arr[0])
        {
            largest = arr[index];
            return highest(arr, index + 1, largest)
        }
        else
        {
            return highest(arr,index + 1, largest)
        }
    }
    return largest;
   
}
var g = [2,22,332,4,5,6,732,3,2,3];

console.log(highest(g, 0))
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: With my codes as posted, i get the wrong answer. I need help to achieve my goal, which is to edit the code somehow so i can get the correct answer 732.

Comment: Why do you do such weired things at all? Use array.sort().pop() and there it is.

Comment: I am in dialema. Should I post the answer which OP should know himself by debugging the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this line:

```
if(arr[index] > arr[0])
```

with

```
if(arr[index] > largest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not discuss why you want to do this and that it can be achieved in other ways. I assume you want to do a recursive sort so i just suggest a more elegant approach.

```
function highest(arr, largest)
{

  largest = largest < arr[0] ? arr[0] : largest;

  if (arr.length == 1) {  
    return largest;
  }
  arr.shift();
  return highest(arr,largest);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursion is not always the answer to efficiency. As an example i give the fibonacci sequence. You need to create some type of memorization object to avoid repeating calculations. You still can use the [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm and get the last item in the array.
But is better to use the simple form by @UniversE